# Google spreadsheet how to count data if contains a value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, count, spreadsheet, countif

been trying to solve this but am struggling. Hopefully this is the right place to ask.

What I need to do is search a row for a certain word, say "cat". If that word is found within that row then take the value of another cell ("Gain") in that row and add this to a total. Then what I need to do is take that total, and divide it by the number of times "cat" was found within a group of rows. Is this possible?

Hopefully that explains what I am trying to do.

For example my data looks likething like this -

```
1       2     3     4         5         Gain
1/6/22  cat   bear  elephant  sheep     7
2/6/22  dog   cat   mouse     cow       12
3/6/33  cat   cow   horse     goat      5

Cow total: 2
Rows containing cow / gain (2/12+5) = 8.5
```

EDIT: What I have noticed it if I use SUMIF it will work ASLONG as the value I am search for is across a single column. However, if it is spreadout across multiple columns I get a value that isn't correct.

Comment: Can you explain how you got 14.5 for cow plz? From your description I would have expected (12+5)/2 = 8.5 ? Also is it possible for cow to appear twice in a row, and would it make a difference to the result?

Comment: Woops, my mistake there. It should be 8.5. I will edit it. And no, something can only appear once in each row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:E3, A6)
```

[image]

and then:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF(B1:E3=A6, F1:F3, ))/COUNTIFS(B1:E3, A6))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula I use when I need to count how many cells have specific values in it within a range:

> =COUNTif($J56:$J956,"=Cat")